# Any way to emulate HORM (hibernate once, resume many) on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

I've read a little about the HORM (hibernate once, resume many) feature introduced in WinXP Embedded.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to emulate that on WinXP Pro?

Basically, I want to reuse my hibernation file so that I can cut the power to my machine and be able to resume it repeatedly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about emulating it, but there are "enthusiasts" who have gotten it working. This is a violation of the license agreement, I'd guess, on Windows XP Embedded.

You can find a cached version of an "enthusiast" procedure here (thanks, Wayback Machine!): http://web.archive.org/web/20071012082424/http://mason.gmu.edu/~sfiorito/eXPinstall.htm

Answer (score 1):

It is a function of Xp Embedded's enhanced write filter.  If you google for enhanced write filter then you will get numerous sets of instructions of how to copy the relevant files over into standard XP.

Alternatively there is a commercial product which builds on the same thing and can add these features to standard XP legitimately (I think MS licenced EWF from them) but unfortunately I cannot remember the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in a VM under VMware or VirtualPC, you can take a snapshot and resume from the snapshot as many times as you like.